# NodeJS Can only connect when Server is shutdown

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Im trying out setting up a webserver with nodeJS with this code:

```
const http = require("http")
const port = 8080
const fs = require("fs")

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" })
    fs.readFile("index.html", function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.write("Error")
        } else {
            res.write(data)
        }
        res.end
        
    })
})

server.listen(port, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong")
    } else {
        console.log("Server is listening on port " + port)
    }
})
```

But when I connect on any browser(tried chrome and mozilla) using either localhost or 127.0.0.1  the page will only show when I shut the server down. It's constantly loading, not showing anything until I shutdown with ctrl + C. Then it will show my HTML page. Same problem was when I didnt use an html page and just responded with

```
res.write("hey")
```

Comment: Well, I think res.end is a function. You didn't call the end function, so the response is not sent to the browser before server is closed. So use res.end() instead of res.end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.end` is a function, try `res.end()`

You had never ended the request so the browser has been waiting for it to end and it only happened when you closed the server.

Answer (score 0):

Because you just show the method

```js
res.end
```

but not run it.